# Luasocket server and actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, lua, server-side, luasocket

I used an example given on the Luasocket website just to try it out, my goal was to make a flash game that'll communicate with the socket.

I run the server and connected to it using telnet at first and it worked, every message I sent appeared on the console so I took it to the next step and connected to it through AS 3 and it did connect but the server won't receive any message even though I constantly write() to it.

Is there anything I'm missing that won't let an actionscript application communicate with the lua socket server?

### Code

```
-- load namespace
local socket = require("socket")
-- create a TCP socket and bind it to the local host, at any port
local server = assert(socket.bind("*", 0))
-- find out which port the OS chose for us
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
-- print a message informing what's up
print("Please telnet to localhost on port " .. port)
print("After connecting, you have 10s to enter a line to be echoed")
-- loop forever waiting for clients
while 1 do
  -- wait for a connection from any client
  local client = server:accept()
  -- make sure we don't block waiting for this client's line
  client:settimeout(10)
  -- receive the line
  local line, err = client:receive()
  -- if there was no error, send it back to the client
  if not err then client:send(line .. "\n") end
  -- done with client, close the object
  client:close()
end
```

### Actionscript:

```
var sock:Socket = new Socket();
sock.connect("127.0.0.1",3335);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,test);
public function test(e:Event):void{
    sock.writeUTF("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: You're missing the part where you post your code.

Comment: @DreamEater there, added.

Answer (score 1):

The standard mode of operation of the client:receive() method is "*l", which waits for a new line character in the input stream to return. http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#receive

To correct this, either send "Hello world\n" (assuming it's the correct escape character in actionscript) or use another parameter in receive().